# Загрузка файла размером 2 Гбайт

Tags: c#, download

Я пользовался **WebClient** но он зависает иногда при загрузке файла размером 2 Гбайт и пишет что файл успешно загружен.

Что можно использовать чтобы скачать файл такого размера?

```
private void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Пожалуйста ожидайте начинаем процесс скачивание клиента", "тест",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Proxy = null;
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://***/test.7z"), @ "test.7z");

}
void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    PicBoxPB.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Клиент успешно скачался,Ожидайте идет процесс распаковки.", "тест", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: Для скачки больших файлов давно придумали Torrent, так что советую воспользоваться им.

Comment: Да ну нее)Какой еще торрент*** на c#

Comment: Ну пример, попробуйте скачать через браузер насколько раз этот файл, скорее всего в какой то момент будет ошибка загрузки.

Comment: Я пробовал ошибки нету

Comment: А какая у вас целевая файловая система?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, используя **ftp web request**, подключаюсь к фтп и оттуда скачиваю файл.